# python gives ImportError: No module named "" when triggered in a perl program

Tags: python, perl

In my perl program which runs the python script

I have provided the PYTHONPATH env param with the path for the lib and i have run the python script. I am getting

ImportError: No module named "....."

```
  my $script = "/path/pythonscript.py";
     $ENV{'PYTHONPATH'} = "/path/lib";
      system("python $script");
```

Whereas when i run the same python script on command line in the same directory where the script executes in my perl program, it is working.

Can anyone give me some pointers on why this is happening.

Comment: What does `$script` contain? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

Try printing the contents of `sys.path` and compare the difference e.g. change your python script to

```py
import sys

print(sys.path)
```

Most likely there is a difference here and this is causing the module to not be found.

Comment: I have tried this already and i see the path is there in both cases of the lib

Comment: Are the paths identical? Is all the python code in the lib dir? or is some of the code in the working directory?  could you perhaps paste the output here?  The python interpreter searches for modules differently when running `python /path/script` compared to  `python script`

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar problem. I solved it by creating an executable script (chmod) and making that script run instead of the python script. The script simply contained a cd to the directory and a python3 program. py

Comment: Why do you think adding another process between Perl and Python will solve anything?

Comment: 'Cause if launched independently from cmd-line the python script MUST start

Comment: That's just superstition. If the shell script can run Python then so can Perl.